# Expo - Share a web link is not showing my app in the list?

Tags: android, expo

I need to share a website link to my expo android app. For example, if I go to browser and type https://www.google.com and then from 3 dots menu if I click share, it should list my app.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: so, you want your app to be available in the list of apps you can share your data to?

Comment: Yes. My app need to show in available list of apps while sharing.

Comment: I am still looking for help. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, i was away for a while. Thing is i can tell you how to do this in native android. This is what you would do in native android : https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive . So, you would need something like this in expo.